# How to use try_emplace in a nested map to still meet the purpose what emplace achieve?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++17, emplace

First I have codes like

```
typedef struct st_A{
    int a = 0;
    string s;

    st_A(const int a, const string&s) :a(a),s(s) {}
}st_A;

map<string, st_A> m1;
```

Now I want to insert a new element of `pair{"c1", st_A{10, "c"}}` into this map, so I code like

```
if (auto it = m1.find("c1"); it == m1.end()){
    //not find
    m1.insert({ "c1", {10, "c"} });
}else{
    ....update by using it....
}
```

But replacing by `try_emplace` I think it would be more concise and efficient

```
auto [it, inserted] = m1.try_emplace("c1", 10, "c");
if (!inserted) {
    ....update by using it....
}
```

So is it really more efficient in the form `try_emplace` than the one of `find+insert`?

And if my original map changes into `map<string, map<int, st_A>> m2`, now I want to insert insert a new element of `pair{"c1", pair{1, st_A{10, "c"}}}`; if I still insist on using `try_emplace`,but it would be ill-formed like

```
auto [it, inserted] = m1.try_emplace("c1", 1, 10, "c");
```

So would it still be suitable this time if using `try_emplace`, and how?

Comment: `typedef struct st_A` This is a C thing, and it is completely unnecessary in C++.

Comment: `find` followed by `insert` (without hint) does 2 lookup. It also constructs mapped object by copy and not "in place".

Comment: You are `find`ing one key, but inserting another. There's no single call that can do both. `insert` et al check for the presence of the same key they are inserting, of course.

Comment: I can't begin to guess what `m1.try_emplace("c1", 1, 10, "c");` is even supposed to do. Each entry in `m1` ultimately contains two strings and one int, but you attempt to pass two ints. Where is the second one supposed to go? Can you describe in English what you are trying to achieve? The code you show is mighty confusing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There are some typos, and I add some description about my goals and what my codes aim to use for

Comment: @Jarod42 But is there a more efficient way by using try_emplace than insert if my map is more complex like `map<string, map<int, st_A>>`

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [insert_or_assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign)?

Answer (score 0):

> So is it really more efficient in the form `try_emplace` than the one of `find`+`insert`?

- `try_emplace` does an unique look-up and potentially contruct in-place.
- `find`+`insert` do 2 look-up and use copy/move constructor.

Another alternative would be `lower_bound`+`insert`(with hint) to reduce the look-up to one, but it would need extra check to see if found iterator is the value or not.

So `try_emplace` win in all circumstance.

> And if my original map changes into `map<string, map<int, st_A>> m2`, now I want to insert insert a new element of `pair{"c1", pair{1, st_A{10, "c"}}};`
> if I still insist on using `try_emplace`, but it would be ill-formed like:
>
> `auto [it, inserted] = m1.try_emplace("c1", 1, 10, "c");`
> So would it still be suitable this time if using try_emplace, and how?

`map` cannot be construct from `pair` (but from `initializer_list<pair<..>>`).

`{..}` has not type, so is problematic in `try_emplace` as-is.

so it would be:

```
auto [it, inserted] = m2.try_emplace("c1", std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, st_A>>{{1, st_A{10, "c"}}});
```

With the caveat that

- you construct the list of pairs anyway
- `initializer_list` content is `const`, so require a copy and not a move.

You might create a proxy type o construct the map only on demand, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct MakeMap
{
    int key;
    int a;
    T s;

    operator std::map<int, st_A>() && { return {{key, {a, s}}}; }
};
```

and

```
auto [it2, inserted2] = m2.try_emplace("c1", MakeMap{1, 10, "c"});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8jdjnYcnG)

Comment: But in your demo, there are still two times of copy ctor of st_A, so does it mean it's the necessary cost to `emplace` in the case of `map<string, map<int, st_A>>`?

Comment: The construction of the map could be with less copy in `MakeMap`: `std::map m; m.emplace(key, a, s); return m;`.